# React npm run build keeps failing

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am struggling to build a react application using `npm run build`. If I use an equivalent docker file and use `npm start` it works fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG APP_MOUNT_URI
ARG API_URI
ARG STATIC_URL
ENV API_URI ${API_URI:-https://example.org/graphql/}
ENV APP_MOUNT_URI ${APP_MOUNT_URI:-/dashboard/}
ENV STATIC_URL ${STATIC_URL:-/dashboard/}
RUN STATIC_URL=${STATIC_URL} API_URI=${API_URI} APP_MOUNT_URI=${APP_MOUNT_URI} 
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build/ /app/
```

I get the following error:

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 466 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! saleor-dashboard@2.10.1 build: `webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the saleor-dashboard@2.10.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-16T19_48_28_830Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

webpack.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require("path");
const CheckerPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

require("dotenv").config();

const resolve = path.resolve.bind(path, __dirname);

const pathsPlugin = new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
  configFile: "./tsconfig.json"
});

const checkerPlugin = new CheckerPlugin({
  eslint: true,
  reportFiles: ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"]
});
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: "index.html",
  hash: true,
  template: "./src/index.html"
});
const environmentPlugin = new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
  "APP_MOUNT_URI",
  "API_URI"
]);

const dashboardBuildPath = "build/dashboard/";

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const devMode = argv.mode !== "production";

  let fileLoaderPath;
  let output;

  export const API_URI = ""

  if(!process.env.API_URI) {
    throw new Error("Environment variable API_URI not set")
  }

  if (!devMode) {
    const publicPath = process.env.STATIC_URL || "/";
    output = {
      chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
      filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
      path: resolve(dashboardBuildPath),
      publicPath
    };
    fileLoaderPath = "file-loader?name=[name].[hash].[ext]";
  } else {
    output = {
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
      filename: "[name].js",
      path: resolve(dashboardBuildPath),
      publicPath: "/"
    };
    fileLoaderPath = "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]";
  }

  return {
    devServer: {
      compress: true,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, dashboardBuildPath),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 9000
    },
    devtool: "sourceMap",
    entry: {
      dashboard: "./src/index.tsx"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            configFile: resolve("./babel.config.js")
          },
          test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/
        },
        {
          include: [
            resolve("node_modules"),
            resolve("assets/fonts"),
            resolve("assets/images"),
            resolve("assets/favicons")
          ],
          loader: fileLoaderPath,
          test: /\.(eot|otf|png|svg|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9.]+)?$/
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      removeAvailableModules: false,
      removeEmptyChunks: false,
      splitChunks: false
    },
    output,
    plugins: [checkerPlugin, environmentPlugin, htmlWebpackPlugin],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      plugins: [pathsPlugin]
    }
  };
};
```

I am really stuck so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What happens when you run `npm start` outside of docker?

Comment: I get the same error. Assume you mean npm run build?

Comment: No I mean `start` because you mentioned that running that with the equivalent docker file. Unless I misunderstood?